# Lust haben, etw zu tun oder Lust darauf haben, etw zu tun?

Tags: grammar, preposition

Is it just a formality distinction whether you use the preposition?

Same thing with

ich bin vorbereitet, Fragen zu beantworten

and

ich bin darauf vorbereitet, Fragen zu beantworten

Or is the preposition only needed for nouns:

Ich bin auf die Pruefung vorbereitet

Answer (score 3):

In this example the preposition can be omitted without changes of nuance or meaning, but it is mandatory for nouns:

> Ich hätte Lust auf einen Kaffee

We also use "Lust dazu".

> Ich habe das Recht es zu verbieten, nicht aber die Lust dazu.

I shall not share my preferences of style, as there is little agreement among native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Ich meine als Infinitivaufhänger wird üblicherweise die kurze Form benützt, meist im Konjunktiv:

- Ich hätte Lust ins Kino zu gehen.

Oder als Frage

- Hast du Lust zum Tanzen zu gehen?

"darauf" könnte man wohl verwenden, aber es ist im Grunde unnötig.